# Manage wireless hosted network in Windows 8 with netsh

Tags: windows-8, wireless-networking, wifi-configuration, netsh

How can I change the password of a hosted network created with `netsh wlan`?

Comment: so I found how to change the key: netsh wlan set hostednetwork key=yourkey

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Super User! Add your solution as an answer, and mark it as accepted!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key of the hosted network can be changed using this command:

```
netsh wlan set hostednetwork key=yourkey keyusage=temporary|persistent
```

See [Netsh Commands for Wireless Local Area Network (WLAN) in Windows Server 2008 R2](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd744890%28v=ws.10%29.aspx#bkmk_wlanSetHostedNet).